# How to resize the linter output in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

This may be a silly question, but I'm having a rough time here - so here goes. The area at the bottom of the window in Atom where I see output from the JS and SCSS linters is too small now. I first noticed this after an update, but this may or may not have anything to do with the update. I used to see 3 lines of errors/warnings at a time, now I can only see one and there are more than one warning. See screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know how to make the output area taller in order to see three or more warnings?